# NoSuchMethodError: No static method beforeCheckcastToFunctionOfArity

Tags: java, android, mockito, kotlin

I have tests for my Android app, written in `Java` using `JUnit4`, `Mockito` and `Espresso`.
I tried to convert them to `Kotlin`, but my tests are failing with this Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method beforeCheckcastToFunctionOfArity(Ljava/lang/Object;I)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lkotlin/jvm/internal/TypeIntrinsics; or its super classes (declaration of 'kotlin.jvm.internal.TypeIntrinsics' appears in /data/app/com.takhfifan.takhfifan-2/base.apk)
at com.takhfifan.takhfifan.activity.AddressSelectActivityTest$configApiToReturnAddresses$1.answer(AddressSelectActivityTest.kt:131)
```

The line that the stacktrace refers, is the second line of this code (the casting):

```
doAnswer { invocation ->
        val resultListener = invocation.arguments[1] as (List<Address>)->Unit
        runLater(after) { resultListener(Arrays.asList<Address>(*addresses)) }
        null
    }.`when`<Api>(api).listCustomerAddresses(any(), any(), any())
```

And the declaration of the function that I am mocking above is like this:

```
open fun listCustomerAddresses(sessionId: String,resultListener: (List<Address>)->Unit, errorListener: (Throwable)->Unit) {...
```

I tried to add this to my proguard file, but nothing changed:

```
-keep class kotlin.jvm.internal.TypeIntrinsics {
    public static Object beforeCheckcastToFunctionOfArity(***);
}
```

Comment: Why are you changing your test language? I think it's good to have application and test with same language

Comment: @VazgenTorosyan I have already changed my application code from Java to Kotlin and now I want to do the same for tests.